# Asymptotic behavior a recursion involving min/max

Tags: asymptotics, recursion

Usually when I face solving recursions I use generating functions but I'm not aware of any "tools" to use when min/max expressions are involved.

For example, I have the following recursive term:
$$T(m,n) = max \{\;T(m/2,m/2)+2T(m/2,n-m/2),\;\; 2T(m,n/2)\;\}$$

(Assume  $T(m,n)=1$  for $m \leq 1$ or $n\leq 1$, I don't care about constants)

It is clear that $mn$ is an upper bound, is there a better (more than by a constant) upper bound or a matching lower bound? Is there some general approach to this kind of stuff?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to solve the recursion, or find asymptotic behavior?

Comment: Asymptotic is enough.

Comment: Have you computed enough terms to make an educated guess?

Comment: Are $(m,n)$ (half) natural numbers or reals? I mean, is there is grid?

Comment: Assume some rounding...